# DynamoDB: How to get to the nested object by id?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have two tables in my DynamoDB:

```
[DynamoDBTable("TVShow")]
public class TVShow
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBRangeKey]
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public double Rate { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty("Episodes")]
    public List<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }
}

[DynamoDBTable("Episode")]
public class Episode
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBRangeKey]
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Sample data:

```
{
  "Episodes": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "Id": {
            "S": "8ab47e73-188c-43e5-8010-1e22a982bb28"
          },
          "Timestamp": {
            "N": "636830978394004950"
          },
          "Title": {
            "S": "First Episode"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "M": {
          "Id": {
            "S": "c477e288-37d1-4d7f-9104-9b72ed304808"
          },
          "Timestamp": {
            "N": "636830978394669182"
          },
          "Title": {
            "S": "Second Episode"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "Id": {
    "S": "466d8a18-f998-49b3-a299-90b508dba045"
  },
  "Rate": {
    "N": "9.3"
  },
  "Timestamp": {
    "N": "636830978390056778"
  },
  "Title": {
    "S": "Vikings"
  }
}
```

> Id: HASH | Partition key
>
> Timestamp: RANGE | Sort key

And I want to get the "Episode First" nested object of TVShow by [Episode] Id.

I have tried many ways to get the data. But didn't work. These are my sources. These documents are not up to date. I am using the AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2 nuget package v3.3.16.5.

Querying Tables and Indexes: .NET
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetQuerying.html

Scanning Tables and Indexes: .NET
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetScanning.html

```
// I can get the TVShow by Id with this.
var scanRequest = new ScanRequest(nameof(TVShow))
{
    FilterExpression = "Id = :Id",
    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
    {
        {":Id", new AttributeValue {S = "466d8a18-f998-49b3-a299-90b508dba045"}}
    }
};

// In the document scan is not async but in v3.3.16.5 scan is async.
var scanResponse = await Client.ScanAsync(scanRequest);


// I can get the TVShow by Id with this.
var queryRequest = new QueryRequest(nameof(TVShow))
{
    KeyConditionExpression = "Id = :Id",
    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
    {
        {":Id", new AttributeValue {S = "466d8a18-f998-49b3-a299-90b508dba045"}}
    }
};

// In the document query is not async but in v3.3.16.5 query is async.
var queryResponse = await Client.QueryAsync(queryRequest);
```

It's okay up here. But as I said that I want to filter by nested object Id or another field like Title. What is the best way for that? If it is possible as Table class.

Comment: If you've two separate tables for TVShow and Episodes then why would you store Episodes in TVShow table as well? Also if you need to search Episode by ID/Title why would you want to search it in TVShow table?

Comment: @AtharKhan I may have thought of it as a relational database. But I need that kind of problem. What would be your suggestion?

Comment: @AtharKhan I don't need Episode table actually but I need Episode list model inside of TV Shows. That should be an ordinary class. But it has many field Title, Detail, ReleaseDate, etc.

Comment: I don't think you can Scan Episode ID/Title the way it is currently set up.

You should consider splitting TVShow and Episodes into two tables. If you've millions of records in your `TVShow` table then using Scan API for searching Episodes will have serious performance impact and you will also need to set up autoscaling unless you are using `on-demand capacity mode`.

My suggestion would be create a separate `Episodes` table and set up required indexes.